# Is it possible to get real-time message backup from whatsapp?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am trying to perform WhatsApp chat analysis and basically want to have the messages instantly transferred into a text file for further processing.

The issue is that WhatsApp does create a local backup daily at around 2:00 am in the `msgstore.db`, however, I wish to receive the texts and media instantly after every message. In a nutshell, is real-time text and media retrieval of WhatsApp messages possible on every message?

P.S. I did try searching online for the mining methods for WhatsApp, but they usually seem to be based on the local backups that have the lowest backup interval of a day, whereas I want it on every message.

**Update:** As suggested by @pette, I tried emulator method and it too is able to perform chat analysis on the daily local backup. I came across many research papers and realized that WhatsApp does not allow for third party apps to sniff on its application.

Also, I tried using automation technique wherein, I use whatsapp web and automate to copy text on every message. But, these techniques are limited to computer application.

Is it possible to pipe-out whatsapp texts to another text file or log file?

Answer (score 2):

you can install an android emulator, as x86, install the apk of whatsapp, mount the disk of your emulator and open msgstore.db, but you can only retrieve the text files

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this does still not solve my question, since msgstore.db is updated on a daily basis and not more frequently (I need on each text). [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111586/all-the-msgstore-in-the-database-of-whatsapp-are-not-being-restored) shall help. Anyway, thanks for the effort and for that I have up-voted you. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi, if you mount the emulator disk, every 2 minutes you can open msgstore.db and grab the messages every 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can use emulator and write a script which will monitor msgstore.db file and date/time it's last time changed. It will be changed when ever new message is received or sent. Than if it's modified u can read messages from it. This is idea, as I am doing same thing on different type of DB with PHP.
Every file has time stamp when it's changed. So give it a try.